# Fixing title page

Tags: spacing

I need to get the exact separation between the two `Hrule`. The original one, looks like this:

[image]

The title "An Unnecessarily Convoluted Academic Title" does not have the same distance between the two `Hrule`. I wanted to have it equal. But when I change from `\HRule\\[0.4cm]` to `\HRule\\[1.5cm]` I get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino font

\begin{document}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
        \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

        \center % Centre everything on the page

        %------------------------------------------------
        %   Headings
        %------------------------------------------------

        \textsc{\LARGE Institution Name}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

        \textsc{\Large Major Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

        \textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

        %------------------------------------------------
        %   Title
        %------------------------------------------------

        \HRule\\[0.4cm]

        {\huge\bfseries An Unnecessarily Convoluted Academic Title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document

        \HRule\\[1.5cm]

        %------------------------------------------------
        %   Author(s)
        %------------------------------------------------

        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \large
                \textit{Author}\\
                B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        ~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright}
                \large
                \textit{Supervisor}\\
                Dr. Caroline \textsc{Becker} % Supervisor's name
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}

        % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
        %{\large\textit{Author}}\\
        %John \textsc{Smith} % Your name

        %------------------------------------------------
        %   Date
        %------------------------------------------------

        \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

        {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

        %------------------------------------------------
        %   Logo
        %------------------------------------------------

        %\vfill\vfill
        %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{placeholder.jpg}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page

    \end{titlepage}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this better? I used `tabularx` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino font

\begin{document}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
        \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

        \center % Centre everything on the page

        %------------------------------------------------
        % Headings
        %------------------------------------------------

        \textsc{\LARGE Institution Name}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

        \textsc{\Large Major Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

        \textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

        %------------------------------------------------
        % Title
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{13pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\midrule[0.5mm]
\huge\bfseries An Unnecessarily Convoluted Academic Title\\
\midrule[0.5mm]
\end{tabularx}
        %------------------------------------------------
        % Author(s)
        %------------------------------------------------
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \large
                \textit{Author}\\
                B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        ~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright}
                \large
                \textit{Supervisor}\\
                Dr. Caroline \textsc{Becker} % Supervisor's name
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}

        % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
        %{\large\textit{Author}}\\
        %John \textsc{Smith} % Your name

        %------------------------------------------------
        % Date
        %------------------------------------------------

        \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

        {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

        %------------------------------------------------
        % Logo
        %------------------------------------------------

        %\vfill\vfill
        %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{placeholder.jpg}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page

    \end{titlepage}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]